# Microsoft SQL Server-specific Parser and Script Generator for Visual Studio > 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, t-sql, parsing

At MSDN, there is a documentation to [**Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql** Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.schema.scriptdom.sql(v=vs.100).aspx) which contains useful **engine for creation and parsing of the T-SQL syntax tree**. However, this seems to be available only with Visual Studio 2008 and 2010.

Did Microsoft produce a successor of this library past the Visual Studio 2010?
Or was the entire thing discontinued?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom` and `Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql` was merged in to a single assembly and was moved out of visual studio and moved in to the Sql Server SDK starting with Server 2012.

It can now be found under the [`Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.aspx) namespace and can be found at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\###\SDK\Assemblies` where `###` is `110` or higher and you have the SDK installed.

When you install the SDK it should register the dll with the GAC so if you just search for `ScriptDom` in the "Add Reference" all installed versions should show up.

[image]

In the above image I have Visual Studio 2010 (version 10), Sql Server 2012 (version 11),  and Sql Server 2014 (version 12) installed on my machine.